# Feeding keras model with multiple inputs

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, valueerror

I am trying to do a simple hello world with Keras and stuck.
At the beginning I had 1 layer with 1 input and 1 output and it worked
pretty well for a straight line approximation ;)

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras.losses import mean_squared_error
mo = Sequential()
d = Dense(1, input_shape=(1,))
mo.add(d)
mo.summary()

mo.compile(loss=mean_squared_error, optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.4), metrics=['accuracy'])

mo.trainable = True

for i in range(-100, 100):
    mo.train_on_batch(x = [i], y = [i])
```

After that I've got bravery for 2 input parameters:

```
d = Dense(1, input_shape=(2,))
for i in range(-100, 100):
    mo.train_on_batch(x = [np.array([i,i])], y = [i])

np.array([1,1]).shape # gives (2,)
```

Though I am getting an exception:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_53_input to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)

I tried various combinations like `[[i],[i]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first dimension is always the batch dimension in Keras. Batch size refers to the number of samples processed in a pass (forward and backward). When you specify the `input_shape` argument it does not include the batch dimension. Therefore, a network with input shape of `(2,)` takes input data of shape `(?,2)` where `?` refers to the batch size. So you must pass arrays of shape `(?,2)`:

```
mo.train_on_batch(x=[np.array([[i,i]])], y=[i])
```

since:

```
np.array([[i,i]]).shape   # it is (1,2)
```